# select first element with specific css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If I have following html structure

```
<div class="col-lg-3 form-group">
    <input id="My_Value" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" value="" name="My.Value" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Choose!">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="My.Value"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    <a class="" title="some title">
</div>
```

When traversing dom if I know `My_Value` how can I select `glyphicon-ok`. 
Worth to mention is there are many elements with `glyphicon-ok` class and I want to select only this first after `My_Value` selector.

Answer (score 3):

Just answer

```
var span_glyphicon_ok  = $('#My_Value').parent().next().find('.glyphicon-ok:first');
```

[parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) => for getting parent div of My_Value

[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) => for getting next element of above div.

[find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) => find glyphicon-ok by class selector

Comment: Also `.find('.glyphicon-ok')[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

You can first use `.parent()` to get parent of `My_Value` then go to `.next()` element and find `glyphicon-ok` element inside it.

```
$("#My_Value").parent("div").next().find(".glyphicon-ok:first")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this Structure, your main `DIV` is `col-lg-1` so you have just focus on that particular `DIV`.

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    <a class="" title="some title">
</div>
```

you just want to pick first `glyphicon` from `col-lg-1` so the process will be like below. and just add one class in the same div which has already class `col-lg-9` like `col-lg-9 glyphicon-wrapper`.

```
.col-lg-9.glyphicon-wrapper > .glyphicon:first-of-type {
    /* Your CSS code will be here */
}
```

`:first-of-type` will be pick first `glyphicon` from the parent div.

Answer (score -1):

There are many jquery selector you want to use. Check below code:-

```
$('#My_Value').parent('.form-group').next().find('.glyphicon-ok:first')
```